aiogram, python. how to get the invitation link that a user used to join a group
I have a bot that provides chat invitation links. The user id and his link are saved in the database. how to get the link through which the user entered the chat?
I tried using various methods such as full_name, as_json() and the like, but none of them returned anything that could help me. json when attached returns
{"id":19..,"is_bot":false,"first_name":"Vansed","last_name":"Dan","username":"...","language_code":" en"}

and my code is the following:
invited_user='Vansed Dan' -
who_invited='{"id":"...,"is_bot":false,"first_name":"Vansed","last_name":"Dan","username":"...","language_code":" en"}'

I also tried to get the invitation link that was changed, and track all joins and check after each join who joined and what invitation code is incremented by 1. but I could not do this, due to the lack of any method for getting chat invitation links, or information about link.
I searched half the Internet but still couldn’t find such a method. and the getChatInviteLink method does not exist, or I don’t know how to use it
import requests

TOKEN = ''
chat_id = ''
invite_link = ''

url = f'https://api.telegram.org/bot{TOKEN}/getChatInviteLink?chat_id={chat_id}&invite_link={invite_link}'

response = requests.get(url)
data = response.json()
print(data)

if data['ok']:
    print(f"{invite_link}:")
    print(data['result'])
else:
    print("error")

